# Pushing citations to LaTeXila from JabRef

Tags: jabref

I've just starting learning the LaTeX ropes in the past couple weeks and I am loving it!! There is just one (last, yeah right!) thing that I am trying to get to work. I'm managing my citations with JabRef, because I really like the easy of editing in the GUI, and although I was planning on entering all my citations manually it appears as if JabRef has a method of pushing citations to LaTeX editors but I can't get it to work with LaTeXila in Ubuntu 12.04. I was wondering if anyone here has set this up and it willing to let me know how it's done.

Sorry if this question has already been answered I was unable to find a solution any where. I am using `natbib` with `\citep` and using the JabRef generated .bib file I am getting exactly the bibliography I want. This would just makes things that one tiny bit easier. Thanks so much!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I do not know if/how this is possible, but can always copy the bibtexkey with Ctrl + Shift + K, or  `\cite{<bibtexkey>}` with Ctrl + K. Not quite as automatic as you would like, but not entirely manual either. (Then again, you were perhaps aware of this, in which please forgive me the noise.)

Comment: Thanks Torbjørn! I did know about that and I know I'm being really picky and I don't really need a solution but the perfectionist part of me wonders if it could be even better.

Comment: Did you find a button for `settings for latexila` inside `jabref preferences` --> `External programs`? If so, you can click it and set it as you wish.

Comment: Thanks @HarishKumar. There is a option for LaTeX editor but when I point JabRef to /usr/bin/latexila (I'm assuming that is correct). It doesn't work. I'm probably missing something.

Answer (score 3):

JabRef can only 'push' citations to programs it is set up to interact with. It has a list of several common ones which provide the necessary 'back end' for this to work. However, LaTeXila is not on the list (the setting for 'LaTeXeditor' is a particular program, LEd, not a generic hook). As such, you have to stick to the 'by hand' root, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to copy `\cite{<key>}` if appropriate. Of course you can also make a feature request for LaTeXila to be added to the 'known' editor list,.